# Does Moment of Courage trigger on evaded attacks?

Tags: dota-2

Does the Legion Commander passive Moment of Courage trigger on an evaded attack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Moment of Courage is triggered when an attack on Legion Commander begins, not when it hits, so it should proc even if the eventual result of the attack is a miss. Watch the spotlight on Legion Commander to see this skill in action:

Comment: Same as Axe's helix or centaur's Return

Comment: And it should proc even if the attack is canceled

Comment: @WizLiz which rarely happens since in his ultimate you cannot abort your attack